# Save actual execution plan for query run as part of SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-execution-plan

I am trying to troubleshoot some poor performance and need to get the actual execution plan for a stored procedure which is run as part of a SSIS package.

There are earlier steps in the SSIS package which run, passing parameters to the stored procedure.

When I try to set those parameters manually within the query as standalone code, the performance is very different.

I know how to get the actual execution plan from within SSMS when running a query, but I don't know how to obtain it when run from a SSIS package. The estimated plans in the cache are not enough.

Is there a way to either show the plan for a particular part of a SSIS package, or generate it and save to a specified location so it can be retrieved after it has run?

I'm probably using the wrong search terms but when I've tried to Google a solution, I just get a bunch of pages explaining how to show the actual execution plan when running a query directly, or find an estimated plan in the cache.

---

**EDIT**

I'm using SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU4)

———

**EDIT 2**

I tried using SQL profiler to obtain the xml plan but found:

 - It was a right faff trying to find the right plan in the trace even when running manually just after starting the trace... would be nigh on impossible to find it amongst an overnight ETL.

Am I doing something wrong? 
Is there a better way?!

Comment: SQL Server 2014 "R2"? There is no R2 for SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @Larnu : sorry, my bad - amended now. Should be SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU4).

Answer (score 1):

you can use SQL Server Profiler to Capturing Graphical Query Plans :

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1264/capturing-graphical-query-plans-with-sql-server-profiler/

Comment: Thanks; after a bit of fiddling around I think I got this to work.
Plan looks a bit different to when running in SSMS though ... ie it includes 'actual rows' but doesn't seem to include the first step eg where memory grant details etc can be found. IS that normal or am I looking in the wrong place?